# Move element to the center of screen as window is resized

Tags: javascript, css

So let's say I have a video with `height: 100%`, and as the browser's width resizes, I want the video to move towards the center using `transform: translateX()`.

A good example of this would be the batmanvsuperman.com website (close the opening trailer to enter the site). As you resize the width (not height) of the browser, the translateX value changes, and the video moves towards the center of the browser.

How would I go about this?

I mocked up the below where I divide the video's width by 2 or whatever number, to get the value for translateX. But this is just guesstimating... I'm trying to get the exact value.

Am I going in the right direction or should I use window.innerWidth somehow?

```
var video = document.querySelector("video");

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    document.querySelector("video").style.transform = "translateX(" + video.offsetWidth/2 + "px)";
})
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Why don't you translate using a percentage? As in 50%? Then the center is always in the center :)

Comment: See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/959uc9LL/1/) maybe it gives you some ideas for centering relative to the _screen_. (The fiddle works only in FF.) If you need to center relative to document or browser window, you should edit the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to calculate with every resize event.

Get the video width. 
Subtract that from window.innerWidth.
Divide that number to two.
Give that to the video element's margin-left or translateX value as pixels.

I assume that video has no translation property beforehand and not padding or margin value.

You can do the same process with height values.

From the example from the question,

```
var video = document.querySelector("video");

    window.addEventListener("resize", function(){

        var videoWidthNumber = parseInt(getComputedStyle(video,null).getPropertyValue('width'));
        var translationX = (window.innerWidth - videoWidthNumber) / 2; 
        video.style.transform = "translateX(" + translationX.toString() + "px)";

    });
```

With JQuery,

```
var video = $("video");

    $(window).on("resize", function(){

        var videoWidthNumber = video.width();            
        var translationX = (window.innerWidth - videoWidthNumber) / 2; 
        video.css("transform","translateX(" + translationX.toString() + "px)");

    });
```

Comment: Can you please provide the associated code as an example of how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use CSS?
The HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="video-container">
        <div class="video">
            <p>Video</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
.video-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.video {
    /* THESE ARE FOR DEMO PURPOSES */
    color: white;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    background: grey;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyvvwQ

Answer (score 0):

If video is on its own or inside a sized container , you may size the `<video>`container itself, the video will resize and center itself and skip javascript to do the job:

**Below 3 snippet to test in full page and then resize window's browser to see behavior**

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin:auto;
}
video {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
 <video  controls muted>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
                </video>
```

If video is not body child but any other sized container , then it works the same :

```css
div {
  width:50vw
  height:50vh;
  /* see me */
  background:gray;
}
video {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
/* center that div with flex:*/
html {
  height:100%;
  display:flex;/* or display:table; + width:100%;*/
}
body {
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div> 
  <video controls muted>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
                </video>
</div>
```

or display:table

```css
div {
  height:50vh;
  /* see me */
  background:gray;
}
video {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
/* center that div :*/
html {
  height:100%;
  display:table;  width:100%;
}
body {
  display:table-cell;  
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
}
video {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div> 
  <video controls muted>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
                </video>
</div>
```